# r shiny - is uploaded data safe and secure?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a shiny app where users upload transaction data to get access to an analytics dashboard.  Can I assure these people that their data is secure from sniffers/hackers and will be removed from the shiny server when their session expires?  How does this actually work in Shiny?  (Note that I'll be hosting my app on shinyapps.io)

Comment: a workaround could be to generate a unique key pair whereby the user is issued a key and their data is tagged with the PEM. Check out packages PKI or sodium för more details

Comment: a workaround for what?

Comment: workaround was the wrong word to use. add a layer of encryption is better way of putting it

Comment: Keys would be unique to the session...if im thinking this through properly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not to do with shiny, but whatever server you're storing the data on, how you're using encryption/hashing, and software/app security methods you've used to protect against specific vulnerabilities.

Having said that, here's the (rather minimal, IMHO) security statement for shinyapps.io:

> shinyapps.io is secure-by-design. Each Shiny application runs in its
>   own protected environment and access is always SSL encrypted. Standard
>   and Professional plans offer user authentication, preventing anonymous
>   visitors from being able to access your applications.

I would say that the burden will heavily fall on you to use good encryption and data storage practices.

There are many official and unofficial guidelines you can look to for guidance on data storage. One which big companies, particularlly companies going public, must follow is Sarbanes-Oxley.

From grtcorp.com:

> The Sarbanes-Oxley Act (SOX Act) was passed by Congress and signed
>   into law in 2002 in response to major cases of financial fraud, of
>   which the rise and collapse of Enron is the best known. The overall
>   focus of the measure is on financial reporting responsibilities, and
>   ensuring that financial audits are genuinely independent.
>
> However, SOX also includes provisions that relate to the **security and
>   preservation of financial data**. And the standards set out for its
>   implementation "recognized that senior management can't just certify
>   controls ON the system, these controls also have to control the way
>   financial information is generated, accessed, collected, stored,
>   processed, transmitted, and used through the system."
>
> Senior management is thus held ultimately responsible for financial
>   data security, including putting in place appropriate controls and
>   procedures to ensure this data security. The good news is that
>   powerful tools, including **data discovery and Data Masking**, are
>   available to meet these standards.

I would also encourage you to familiarize yourself with OWASP's list of the top 10 major web app vulnerabilities:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

Comment: I'm not doing any data storage.  I just don't want to tell people that their data is removed from the server when their session ends if it actually gets cleared nightly or something of the like.

Comment: @Ben For something that specific you'd need to write shinyapps.io, however may I ask how you're avoiding storing data? You're selling stuff but not keeping a record of transactions? I guess you must be managing everything through some other system like PayPal (not a bad idea)? Are you using the pro version with logins and authentication? I'm just curious. It may be a good idea to use certifications to assure users of safety.

Comment: It's a free app for the time being, but I was considering using the premium shinapps.io plan and just manually maintaining user logins as people people me via paypal (or some other system).

Comment: @Ben Yes, I think it's a good idea to keep all of the financial transactions and data storage off of shinyapps as possible. That way you can rely on the reputation and security of your remote services like PayPal. If you get into using persistent data later your options are described in the following link and I'd recommend again using reputable services that come with security https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html