# Security of Files Uploaded to RShiny--Not Persistent

Tags: r, security, file-upload, shinyapps

I'm thinking about building an RShiny app to handle some system evaluation, and I'd like to share it with colleagues outside my organization. I've built apps before where you simply upload a few specified files and work with that data in that session, but I'm not sure what happens to  the uploaded files after the session terminates? This would strictly be an app to upload files, view some pertinent information about them, and then download a generated Excel file. If they want to use it again, they would have to re-upload the files--I'm not writing anything at all to store that information because the standard files we use contain PII (not HIPAA).

However! I'm not sure whether that information still lives on a server somewhere after the session terminates, even if *I'm* not telling my app to save it. [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40879254/r-shiny-is-uploaded-data-safe-and-secure) the most relevant response was that the asker should ask shinyapps.io directly, but that was a few years ago so I'm hoping we know now because their website says they are unable to answer security questions. The [RStudio website](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html) says that "the app will only save responses within its R session" without specific instructions to the contrary from the writer, but it also says [here](https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/security-and-compliance.html) that "The storage for each container is not permanent, so if you need to store data, our strong recommendation is for you to push that data into your own data store." That second piece does sound like it is stored somewhere? Most things I've done have been local so I'm less familiar with remote security, and I really don't want to mess this up! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hey @eggeggboyegg - you may get better replies over on the community.rstudio.com site. I would suggest posting this question over there.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else stumbles on this, this documentation answered my questions well enough:

"The storage will be persistent while the application is in the Running state. After the idle timeout is reached, the application will be put into a Sleeping state, and any changes to the file system will be lost."
https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/Storage.html#understanding-the-storage-lifecycle